# How can i find this limit? It has a factorial and an nth root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2}n*(n!)^{\frac{1}n}$
How can I calculate this limit? I can't even use lhopital's rulr because of the factorial... it is in an analysis class so feel free to use any theorems

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stirling%27s+approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Stirling: I'll deal with $\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{1/n}.$ Apply $\ln $ to this expression to get

$$\tag 1 -\ln n +\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k= -\ln n +\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln[(k/n)n].$$

This works out to be $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k/n)\frac{1}{n}.$ This is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \ln x\ dx =-1$.

Now exponentiate to see the limit of $\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{1/n}$ is $\frac{1}{e}.$ Put the factor $2$ back in to see the desired limit is $\frac{2}{e}.$

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing Stirling's Approximation, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((2 \pi n)^{1/2} n^n/c^n)^{1/n} \cdot 2 }n = \frac 2 c \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((2 \pi n)^{1/2} n^n)^{1/n}}n=\frac 2 c \cdot 1$$

Comment: What is $c$?  Do you mean $\mathrm{e}$?

Comment: Yes, it’s e. Limit is 2/e.

Comment: @XanderHenderson $c$ is any positive real. In the case of the question $c=e$.